# Could someone explain the meaning of vector<Node*>()

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, default-constructor, copy-assignment

I'm solving the Clone Graph in Leetcode, but I encountered a problem inside the following codes

```
 class Node {
public:
    int val;
    vector<Node*> neighbors;
    Node() {
        val = 0;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }
    Node(int _val) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }
    Node(int _val, vector<Node*> _neighbors) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = _neighbors;
    }
};
```

what does it mean by the statement `neighbors = vector<Node*>();`. More specifically, `vector<Node*>()`. Why is it followed by parentheses?

Comment: You should probably learn about [objects](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_classes.asp), [pointers](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_pointers.asp) and [vectors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/)

Comment: What would `Node a = Node()` do?

Comment: Sites such as LeetCode assume you know the computer language you will be using to solve the problem.  If you are asking basic questions about C++ such as this, maybe you chose the wrong language to try and solve the LeetCode problem.  LeetCode and other such sites are not in the business of teaching you C++.

Comment: Get your favorite book about `c++` and look up constructors.

Comment: It doesn't do anything here because `neighbors` was already initialized with its default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this statement in the constructors of the class Node

```
neighbors = vector<Node*>();
```

is redundant.

There is used the move assignment operator that assigns an empty vector created by calling the default constructor `vector<Node*>()` of the class `std::vector<Node *>` to the already created empty vector `neighbors` that is a data member of the class Node.

You may remove this statement from the constructors of the class Node. In fact it has no effect.